# Multiple Client Connections Management with ExecutorService

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, tcpserver

I am trying to create a TCP Server in Java, However I am using the ExecutorService to service client connection requests  in a class called `ServerService`.

Like this:

```
public class ServerService extends Thread
{
    final Settings settings = SystemSettings.getInstance();

    private final ThreadPoolExecutor client_pool = 
        (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
        settings.getNo_of_client_connections(), new ClientThreadFactory()); 
     ServerSocket server ;
     Socket client_socket ;

    public void run()
    {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4000);

            while(!client_pool.isShutDown()) {
                client = server.accept();
                // call client connection runnable to continue processing from here 
                ClientConnection client_connection = new ClientConnection(client);
                client_pool.execute(client_connection);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            LoggerService.log(ex);
        }

        finally {
            client.close(); 
        }
    }

    // shutdown service 
    public synchronized void shutdown() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        if(client_pool != null) { 
            client_pool.shutdown();
            client_pool.awaitTermination(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            client_pool.shutdownNow();
            System.out.println("Service has been shutdown ........");
        }     

    }
}
```

Then I have my `ClientConnection` class that processes requests from clients once a connection has been made.

```
public class ClientConnection implements Runnable 
{
    Socket socket ;
    private  ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    private static  boolean isInterrupted = false ;

    public ClientConnection(Socket socket)
    {
        this.socket = socket ;
   }

    public void run()
    {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), 10240));

        // write a session client id to client for 
        write(new Response(ResponseCommand.CLIENT_ID_SESSION_ID, CLIENT_ID)); // chicken egg problem 
        System.out.println(getClient_id() +" connected....");
        // create a buffer  size of 10kb for reading data from client 
        ois = new ObjectInputStream( new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), 10240));

        try {   
            // as far as the thread running this runnable in my pool is not interrupted
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Object request = ois.readObject();

                if(request != null) {
                    // get request object 
                    Request rq = (Request)request;

                    if(rq.getComand().equlasIgnoreCase("EXIT")) {
                        isInterrupted = true ;

                        // interrupt thread running in my pool 
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            LoggerService.log(ex);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            LoggerService.log(ex);
            Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
        } finally {
            if(isInterupted) {
                socket.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now these are my questions:

1. When I send a termination request from a client how do I keep my
   `ClientConnection` (`Runnable`) in sync with my Thread Pool because I
   start my thread pool with a fixed number of threads e.g 10 so when
   one of the threads is interrupted it closes the socket connection and
   should be ready to process another client.
2. How do I model my `RejectedExecutionHandler` to display an error
   when the fixed amount of connections in the pool has been exceeded?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. when the runnable is finished, the thread in the pool automatically becomes available to execute another one. You don't need to do anything. 2. What have you tried?

Comment: I just interrupted the currently running thread and terminate the socket connection , however when i try to connect with another client the connection request is refused .

Comment: Put a log/`System.out.println(...)` in `ClientConnection.run()` in the EXIT block, and see if you get the same number of such printouts as you do interrupts, or monitor your `ThreadPoolExecutor` another way.  If this is an educational exercise, then check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818248/java-socket-programming-with-concurrent-i-o